# SSDT 2015 - Release, Deploy, and Parameters

Tags: visual-studio-2015, ssis, sql-server-data-tools

I am stumped when it comes to setting project and package parameters in release and deploy. Their values don't appear on server when the ispac is run, but they are set in development environment of VS2015.

- How do I set parameters make them persist on the server on deployment?

For bonus points:

- How do I set parameters relevant to build configuration?

Thanks in advance,

Andrew

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a big miss in the project deployment model.  Environments are not automatically created and configured when the project is deployed.  The manual way to deal with this is to:

1. Create an environment
2. Add the parameters to the environment
3. Add the environment to the project
4. Associate the parameters in the environment with the ones in project

This approach is usually ok as parameters do not change that often.
If you want to implement a more consistent deployment practice, you could script this out in powershell.  Matt Mason shows how to do that here:

https://www.mattmasson.com/2012/06/publish-to-ssis-catalog-using-powershell/

His example uses hardcoded values, which usually does not work across environments.  Alternatively, you might store the values in a json file (one per environment) and reference that in the script.  Or you could go all the way and use a tool like Octopus Deploy ( https://octopus.com/ ) to store your values per environment.

On one final note, I have found SSIS to be fussy about the build config, especially across multiple users in a CI setting.  i.e. sometimes the project would build to the "development" folder even when it has been changed to build elsewhere.  I would suggest going with the default there and managing parameter values with a release management tool as noted above.

Good luck,
m

Comment: Thanks for that answer. Let's hope Microsoft get things sorted soon.